# Worst-case time complexity for adding two binary numbers using bit manipulation

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

I'm looking over the solution to adding 2 binary numbers, using the bit manipulation approach. The input are 2 binary-number strings, and the expected output is the string for the binary addition result.

Here is the Java code similar to the solution,

```
class BinaryAddition {
  public String addBinary(String a, String b) {
    BigInteger x = new BigInteger(a, 2);
    BigInteger y = new BigInteger(b, 2);
    BigInteger zero = new BigInteger("0", 2);
    BigInteger carry, answer;
    while (y.compareTo(zero) != 0) {
      answer = x.xor(y);
      carry = x.and(y).shiftLeft(1);
      x = answer;
      y = carry;
    }
    return x.toString(2);
  }
}
```

While the algorithm makes a lot of sense, I'm somehow arriving at a different worst-case time complexity than the `O(M + N)` stated in the Leetcode solution, where `M, N` refers to the lengths of input strings.

In my opinion, it should be `O(max(M, N)^2)`, since the while loop can run up to `max(M, N)` times, and each iteration can take `max(M, N)` operations. For example, adding 1111 and 1001 would take 4 iterations of the while loop.

Appreciate your advice on this or where I might have gone wrong, thanks.

Comment: Hi! Your link tells me "Subscribe to unlock". I can't see the code you're referring to, so I can't guarantee that it's not max(M, N)^2. But addition *should* be O(M+N) if it's done correctly. Note that O(M+N) and O(max(M, N)) are two different notations for the same set, because max(M, N) <= M+N <= 2 max(M, N).

Comment: Please do not rely on external links to explain your question.  It's OK to have links as supplemental information, but it is important to provide enough information *here* that your question can be answered without being dependent on an external site that we do not control (or cannot necessarily access).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments! I just removed the external link, and provided the code of the algorithms that is presented to me. It seems to me that the while loop in this implementation can run up to ```max(M, N)``` iterations.